# How to read CSV columns into vectors in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a CSV file:
[My CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNAjt.png)

I want to create a map as such:

```
((A -> Vector(10.75,10.75,10.47,...,..), B-> Vector(164.56,164.99,160.98,...), C -> Vector(7.1,7.4,9.4,...,), D - > Vector(14.2,14.8,18.8,...,..))
```

This is what I have so far (No much):

```
val source=Source.fromFile("train3.csv")
var firstLine = source.getLines.find(_ => true).get
println(firstLine)
source.getLines().foreach(line=>{
  val lines = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toVector
  println(cols)
})
source.close()
```

This code prints this:
[What my code prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgdfD.png)

My Vectors contain the rows, I need my Vectors to contain the columns and not the rows from the CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, please don't post important text information as an image. We can't copy-paste from images.

I created a smaller test file as follows:

```
A,B,C
10.75,10.75,10.47
164.56,164.99,160.98
7.1,7.4,9.4
14.2,14.8,18.8
```

With that in place I ran it through this code.

```
util.Using(io.Source.fromFile("train3.csv")){
  _.getLines()
   .map(_.split(","))
   .toVector
   .transpose
   .groupMapReduce(_.head)(_.tail.map(_.toFloat))(_++_)
}  //file is auto-closed

//res0: Try[Map[String,Vector[Float]]] =
// Success(Map(A -> Vector(10.75, 164.56, 7.1, 14.2)
//           , B -> Vector(10.75, 164.99, 7.4, 14.8)
//           , C -> Vector(10.47, 160.98, 9.4, 18.8)))
```

This will return `Failure()` if the file can't be opened, or the row lengths aren't consistent, or the number strings can't be converted. (Which might not be required. I just assumed it would be desirable.)

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot for your answer.
The result Im looking for contains the columns in the vectors, as such:
A -> Vector(10.75,10.75,10.47,...,..), B-> Vector(164.56,164.99,160.98,...), C -> Vector(7.1,7.4,9.4,...,), D - > Vector(14.2,14.8,18.8,...,..)

Your result shows each line in a vector, which is something that I've managed to do.

I will make sure to not post code as a photo next time.

Comment: Look again @babilon1210. Since I couldn't copy-paste from your image, I did a copy-paste from the `Map` you posted and I edited it down to just the data. So the raw input file, which I posted, isn't what you have for input, but it demonstrates that the code does exactly what you've asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read the lines, and have something like
`val lines: Seq[Seq[String]] = ???`, just do

```
   val columns = "ABC..."
   lines
     .iterator
     .map { row => columns.zip(row) }
     .groupBy { _._1 }
     .mapValues { _._2 }
     .toMap
```

If you want it specifically to be `Vectors` for some weird reason, then just add `.to[Vector]` after `_._2`