# How to rotate a 90-degree asymmetric matrix using Scala recursion

Tags: java, scala, recursion, matrix, functional-programming

I'm writing a simple anomaly detector for time-series data in Scala.
I need to rotate a matrix by 90 degrees or find a better way to have a map[String,Vector[Double] that holds the data.
I get the information in a csv file as follows:

for example -

A,B,C,D 
1,2,3,2
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
4,5,6,7
5,6,7,8

Now the first line holds the feature names, and each feature column is the data that has been collected for that feature.
I need to have the data in a map as key-value pairs.

[image: Data as Map]

my TimeSeries class

```
class TimeSeries(csvFileName: String) {

private val source = Source.fromFile(csvFileName)

val features = source.getLines.take(1).toVector(0).split(',').toVector // seek at line 2 

val featuresMap = {
val dataRevered: Array[Array[Double]] = 
source.getLines().map(_.split(",").map(_.trim.toDouble)) // Making lines to matrix of 
doubles
  .toArray
source.close()

val data: Array[Array[Double]] = Array.ofDim(dataRevered(0).length, dataRevered.length)

for (i <- 0 until dataRevered.length )
  for (j <- 0 until  dataRevered(0).length )
    data(j)(i) = dataRevered(i)(j) // Not efficient
(features zip data.map(item => item.toVector)).toMap
 }

}
```

Now I know that in Scala we prefer to use recursion rather than loops. If anyone knows the right way how to do it please share with me. (to get a map with the feature name (key) and his column (value) or fill the matrix in a recursion instead of loops)

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67038894/4993128)?

Comment: Yes, that perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Yes absolutely but I can't see it. Where I should see it?

Comment: @jwvh hey thanks again for your help. I need to check if the return value is a Map, got any idea how to check if it succeeds or failed?

Comment: There are several ways to process a `Try` result. The most basic, and easiest to read and understand, is via pattern matching: `result match { case Success(res) =>` ... `case Failure(x) =>` ...